# Replace multiple similar items in a list with just 1

Tags: python

I am working with a list that contains a list of character names based on their appearance in a script but some of them have multiple aliases that are only slightly different. What I want to do is be able to count the number of times the character appears in the script.

```
my_dict = {i:new_list.count(i) for i in new_list}
print(my_dict)
{'NICK FURY': 110, 'AGENT PHIL COULSON': 48, 'AGENT MARIA HILL': 24, 'SELVIG': 15, 'CLINT BARTON': 23, 'LOKI': 72, 'NATASHA': 73, 'BANNER': 79, 'STEVE (V.O.)': 2, 'STEVE': 74, 'TONY': 130, 'JARVIS': 11, 'CAPTAIN AMERICA': 39, 'IRON MAN': 23, 'NICK FURY (V.O.)': 6, 'THOR': 50, 'LOKI (V.O.)': 2, 'TONY (V.O.)': 1, 'CAPTAIN AMERICA (V.O.)': 3, 'BLACK WIDOW (V.O.)': 2, 'HAWKEYE': 10, 'BLACK WIDOW': 18, 'IRON MAN (V.O.)': 4, 'HAWKEYE (V.O.)': 1, 'HULK': 1}
```

The code above counts the occurrence of each element in the list. But as you can see it treats 'IRON MAN' separate from 'TONY' and also separates the '(V.O.)' aspects of the script. I found a method to replace all of this but it's very long.

```
new_list[:] = [s.replace('NICK FURY (V.O.)', 'NICK FURY') for s in new_list]
new_list[:] = [s.replace('STEVE (V.O.)', 'STEVE') for s in new_list]
new_list[:] = [s.replace('LOKI (V.O.)', 'LOKI') for s in new_list]
new_list[:] = [s.replace('BLACK WIDOW (V.O.)', 'NATASHA') for s in new_list]
new_list[:] = [s.replace('BLACK WIDOW', 'NATASHA') for s in new_list]
new_list[:] = [s.replace('TONY (V.O.)', 'TONY') for s in new_list]
new_list[:] = [s.replace('IRON MAN', 'TONY') for s in new_list]
new_list[:] = [s.replace('IRON MAN (V.O.)', 'TONY') for s in new_list]
new_list[:] = [s.replace('CAPTAIN AMERICA', 'STEVE') for s in new_list]
new_list[:] = [s.replace('HAWKEYE (V.O.)', 'CLINT BARTON') for s in new_list]
new_list[:] = [s.replace('HAWKEYE', 'CLINT BARTON') for s in new_list]
new_list[:] = [s.replace('HULK', 'BANNER') for s in new_list]
```

This does give me the desired output which is:

```
my_dict = {i:new_list.count(i) for i in new_list}
print(my_dict)
{'NICK FURY': 116, 'AGENT PHIL COULSON': 48, 'AGENT MARIA HILL': 24, 'SELVIG': 15, 'CLINT BARTON': 34, 'LOKI': 74, 'NATASHA': 93, 'BANNER': 80, 'STEVE': 118, 'TONY': 158, 'JARVIS': 11, 'THOR': 50}
```

But is there a better way to do this?

Comment: if the code works, don't touch it.

Comment: This is better-suited for [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @IgorRaush thanks I will take it over there